# RAD Studio XE8 behave strange

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am using RAD Studio XE8 i have a strange issue when press enter the text line in IDE is not moving to next line or when i press the spacebar it starts to remove the text followed by the space.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in **overwrite** mode. This can be discerned both from the behaviour you describe and that "overwrite"  is written In the status bar underneath the edit window.

In **overwrite** mode, text that you type overwrites the existing text at the cursor. In **insert** mode, typing inserts the text before the cursor.

Press the <kbd>INS</kbd> key to toggle between **overwrite** and **insert** modes.

This behaviour is typical of any text editing program. You will find the same behaviour in other IDEs, in text editors, in word processors and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This is not limited to Delphi XE8, but you have pressed the insert key on your keyboard.

The solution is to press it again to toggle the insert state.